# workspace is already in use issue

Tags: talend

I don't understand why I'm getting a workspace error saying

> This workspace is already in use. You cannot launch the Studio more than once with the same workspace

i already install the JDK8

[image]

Comment: did you try to restart you Laptop

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error too, I installed Talend under C:\Program Files, but you should install it directly in C:\Talend

see this link:
https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00007vClniCAC/resolved-workspace-error-this-workspace-is-already-in-use?language=en_US

hopefully this helps!

Comment: This seems to be a permission issue, Talend can't create the workspace, therefore it throws the error